# speeding up android emulator

Tags: android, performance, android-emulator

as an android developer I have experienced a lot of troubles due to the **lack of speed** in the android emulator. in some instances I had had to wait about three minutes in order to get a response. so is there any way to speed up the android emulator as it took much of development time which in most cases quite valuable.

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5154636

Comment: Please refer the link [Android emulator so slow?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [GenyMotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the native emulator, try using the Android OS in a virtual machine.  http://www.bobbychanblog.com/2011/07/faster-android-emulator-alternative-using-virtualbox/. Hope it helps.

Comment: yes it is faster and better but why don't you go for device debugging ??

Comment: I am new to android development and for the moment I don't have one. anyway thanks for the help.......

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Genymotion third-party Android emulator? The stock one is notoriously slow.

http://www.genymotion.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Bluestacks](http://bluestacks-app-player.en.uptodown.com/) or [GenyMotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) as alternative.